# Kivy:Can't put 'BorderImage' at the specified position

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

(1) By using the following ***kv*** file version was able to place `BorderImage`widget at the specified position..

```
<Screen>:
    ProgressBar:
        max: 100
        pos_hint: {'top':0.86, 'x':0.01}
        size_hint_x: 0.49
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        canvas:
            BorderImage:
                border: (10, 10, 10, 10)
                pos: self.x, self.center_y
                size: self.width, 8
                source: '0.png'
```

(2) But, the following ***Pure Python*** code that should realize the same function as (1) doesn't work properly.`BorderImage`widget is placed at the **bottom** of the screen.
`pos_hint={'top':0.86,'x':0.01}` doesn't work.
I think that how to specify `pos=(bar.x, bar.center_y)` is not good because `bar.center_y` value is different from the code of (1).

```
class BarWidget(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BarWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.build()
    def build(self):
        bar = ProgressBar(pos_hint={'top':0.86,'x':0.01}, max=100, size_hint_x=0.49, size_hint_y=0.1)
        with bar.canvas:
            BorderImage(border=(10, 10, 10, 10), pos=(bar.x, bar.center_y), size=(self.width/2, 8), source='0.png')
        self.add_widget(bar)
```

How should I modify `bar.center_y`?

[(1):screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpvsE.png)

[(2):screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4vsS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the kv language, when you set an attribute like `size: self.size`, this attribute is automatically updated whenever the 'self' widget changes size of shape. When things are loading up in a screen/layout, they start with funky positions and sizes then move to be correct. Since things automatically update upon changing sizes/positions if you work in kv, it works as you expect.

In python, you have to explicitly bind some function to update the canvas if the size or position of the widget it's inheriting its size and pos from changes. You can do that by using the `bind` function (available in most/all kivy widgets). Using `bind`, you can say `bind(<attribute>=<function>)` which means anytime the widget's `<attribute>`, aka size or pos, is changed, it calls the `<function>`

I didn't test this exactly with your code since not all of it is posted, but this is what I do for my projects. Let me know how it works. If it doesn't work, edit your answer to be a snippet of code that I can copy/paste to work with and I'll update my answer.

```
class BarWidget(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BarWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.build()
    def build(self):
        # Make it so you can reference the bar and border image later
        self.bar = ProgressBar(pos_hint={'top':0.86,'x':0.01}, max=100, size_hint_x=0.49, size_hint_y=0.1)
        with self.bar.canvas:
            # Make it so you can reference the border image
            self.border_image = BorderImage(border=(10, 10, 10, 10), pos=(bar.x, bar.center_y), size=(self.width, 8), source='0.png')
        self.add_widget(self.bar)
        # Make it so whenever the widget's pos or size changes, we update the border image
        self.bar.bind(pos=self.update_border_image, size=self.update_border_image)
    # make a function to update border image
    def update_border_image(self, *args):
        self.border_image.size = (self.width, 8) # Should this 8 be 0.8 by the way?
        self.border_image.pos = (self.bar.x, self.bar.center_y)
```

Comment: Thank you for useful infomation.I tried the code you offered, it worked but the position of `BorderImage`widget did not change. I think that the point of  your answer is to use `bind` and update position for changing screen size or parent widget size.It is the problem that the initial position of `BorderImage`widget does not go well...

Comment: I added screen shots of the result(1) and (2).

Comment: It was my lack of understanding.I corrected the part of `self.bind(pos=self.update_border_image, size=self.update_border_image)` to `self.bar.bind(pos=self.update_border_image, size=self.update_border_image)`, it worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: Happy to hear you got it! :)